# VBA transferring data to another workbook with major adjustments - doable?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to move a large amount of data from workbook A to workbook B in excel - workbook A has a different organizational structure than workbook B, and I want to automate A to transfer to B and organize itself into B's structure. I'm just getting acquainted with VBA, but before potentially wasting a lot of time - is this something VBA can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely, as long as you have a reliable set of steps for translating the information from one format to another.  If that's the case, then they can be codified and implemented in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just getting acquainted with VBA, do some cost-benefit analysis. Sometimes it's faster to do it by hand. That being said, it will be very satisfying if you can get it to work. Nothing like going on a coffee break while your work does itself.